# How do I find elements inside of elements using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I can't figure out the syntax to return the specific elements in this HTML example.

```html
<div class="calibre" id="calibre_link-0">
    <div class="book" title="Chapter 11. Web Scraping">
        <div class="titlepage">
            <div class="book">
                <div class="book">
                    <h1 class="title1"><a id="calibre_link-2915" class="firstname"></a>Web Scraping</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I have tried is `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div.calibre.div')` and also using
`('div.calibre .div') | ('div.calibre + div')` and other variations on those. I have managed to return all the div elements in the page but I just want to return all of the ones nested within the **calibre** class (i.e. book, titlepage, book, and book). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts, not in question posts. Please roll back the addition of the answer into this post. You can get at the unformatted answer text by clicking 'edited' then on 'edit' for the last version. But if another suggested question has an answer that answers your question please don't answer but click to agree that your question is a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's only one element with the class 'calibre' and it's the one you need, you can do:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('calibre').find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
```

When you execute `driver.find_element_by_class_name('calibre')` (or any other `driver.find...` function for that matter), that call returns an object that has the same methods as driver. In other words, you get a piece of the webpage that you can navigate as you would the whole webpage.

In this case, `driver.find_element_by_class_name('calibre')` will return a portion of the webpage with de element whose class is 'calibre' and all it's children. To access it's divs, you should navigate it with `find_elements_by_tag_name`.