# Selenium only clicking on first result

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click through many results coming from Selenium using css selector but the driver just keep clicking the same first result and ignoring the others. Any idea why is this happening? Here is the code:

```
def scrape(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(' - incognito')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    browser.get(url)

    timeout = 20

    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_33itj _2fdV7 _1xUb6']")
            )
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout waiting for page to load")
        browser.quit()
    
    

    
    #links = set()
    for i in range(0, 30):
        store_element = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3B5De")
        store_element[i].click()

        try:
            performance = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='_1LnDa']")
            print(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3sxJP"))
        except IOError:
            print('retry')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('No such element')
        else:
            break
```

Comment: are you choosing element inside a combo box?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's not a combo box, it's just listed items inside a div

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400472/how-do-i-find-elements-inside-of-elements-using-selenium-with-python

Comment: are you sure it's not clicking on the others but still delivering info about the first? Within your try instead of browser.find, see what happens if you say store_element[i].find

Comment: @JeremyKahan I get `'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find'` and if I use `find_element_by_xpath` I keep getting an error: `'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: that is surprising. Thanks for the update. I still think the key is to look for your fields within the i-th item, as opposed to just within the browser, and then it matches 30 and gives you the first. If there is one each, probably you could do things like performance = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_1LnDa']"[i]

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyKahan. It was getting empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to select options inside a combo box in your webpage 1st try to load all your selectable options inside a variable using this module:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

and then select any option you wanted using by select_by_index method in selenium.
a sample code look like this:

```
for i in range(0, 30):
    s2=Select(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3B5De"))
    s2.select_by_index(i).click()
```

or might be this:

```
s2=Select(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3B5De"))
for i in range(0, 30):
    s2.select_by_index(i).click()
```