# Locating a specific instance of a class located using XPath with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, nested-loops

I am trying, using Selenium, to click the PDF icon (shown in screenshot 2) for each element (each of the containers shown in screenshot 1).

The problem is that the identifiers for the PDF icons are limited, so I am restricted to locating them with an XPath expression by class. At each iteration of the `for elem in issues_numb:` statement, the script clicks the first PDF icon it finds on the page, as it is the first element associated with the XPath fed to the script.

Is there a way to create a nested loop that for each instance of a class (article titles) clicks the instance of another class (PDF icons) that's associated to it? So for the first article, click the first PDF icon, etc...

**HTML code:**

```html
<section aria-label="Metadata for Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea" class="article-list-item-content-block ">
    <div class="title " data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1069="1069">
        <div id="ember1070" class="ember-view"><a target="_blank" href="/libraries/1374/articles/504204400" id="ember1071" class="ember-view" tabindex="0"> Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!---->

    <div class="metadata">

        <!---->

        <span tabindex="0" class="pages ">
            p. 489
        </span>

        <!---->

        <span class="authors" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1082="1082">
            <span tabindex="0" class="preview tabindex">
                Iqbal, Sajid; Vohra, Muhammad Sufyan; Janjua, Hussnain Ahmed
            </span>
        </span>

        <div class="abstract" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1083="1083">
            <div tabindex="0" class="preview tabindex">
                <div id="ember1088" class="ember-view">
                    <span class="lt-line-clamp__line">In the current study, strain MW-6 isolated from Arabian seawater exhibited broad-spectrum antibacterial activity</span>
                   <span class="lt-line-clamp__line">against indicator bacterial pathogens. The partially extracted antibacterial metabolites with ethyl acetate revealed</span>
                   <span class="lt-line-clamp__line lt-line-clamp__line--last">
                       promising activity against, and. The minimum inhibitory concentrations (MICs) were determined against indicator stra<span class="lt-line-clamp__ellipsis"><div class="lt-line-clamp__dummy-element">…</div>

                       <!---->
                    </span></span>

                    <!----><span class="lt-line-clamp__ellipsis lt-line-clamp__ellipsis--dummy">…</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!---->

            <div class="content-overflow " data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1089="1089">
                <span class="chevron icon flaticon solid down-2"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="tools ">
              <div class="buttons noselect">
                    <div class="button invisible download-pdf" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1090="1090">
                        <div id="ember1091" class="ember-view"><a aria-label="Download PDF" target="_blank" href="/libraries/1374/articles/504204400/pdf" id="ember1092" class="tooltip ember-view" tabindex="0">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon fal fa-file-pdf"></span>
                            <span class="aria-hidden">Download PDF - Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="button invisible read-full-text" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1097="1097">
                    <div id="ember1098" class="ember-view"><a aria-label="Link to Article" target="_blank" href="/libraries/1374/articles/504204400" id="ember1099" class="tooltip ember-view" tabindex="0">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon fal fa-link"></span>
                        <span class="aria-hidden">Link to Article - Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button invisible add-to-my-articles" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1100="1100">
              <a aria-label="Save to My Articles" class="tabindex tooltip" tabindex="0">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon fal fa-folder"></span>
                <span class="aria-hidden">Save to My Articles - Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button invisible citation-services" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2165="2165">
              <a tabindex="0" aria-label="Export Citation" class="tabindex tooltip">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon fal fa-graduation-cap"></span>
                <span class="aria-hidden">Export Citation - Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="button invisible social-media-services" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2166="2166">
              <a tabindex="0" aria-label="Share" class="tabindex tooltip">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon fal fa-share-alt"></span>
                <span class="aria-hidden">Share - Whole-genome sequence and broad-spectrum antibacterial activity of Chryseobacterium cucumeris strain MW-6 isolated from the Arabian Sea</span>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**My code:**

```python
issues_numb = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//section[@class='article-list-item-content-block ']")
parent_tab = driver.current_window_handle


for elem in issues_numb:
    title_article = elem.get_attribute("aria-label")
    print(title_article[13:])
    try:
        check_buttons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
        print("pdf object found for", str(elem))
        checking_size_buttons = len(str(check_buttons))
        if checking_size_buttons > 0:
            pdf_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
            click_pdf = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pdf_icon).click(pdf_icon).perform()
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
            check_need_to_sign_in()
            driver.switch_to.window(parent_tab)
        else:
            print("No PDF available")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        get_article_name()
```

The `issues_numb` variable refers to this element:

[image]

The `tools_box` variable refers to this element:

[image]

Comment: Is the site public? Something to be aware of if storing elements is the possibility of later stale element exceptions if an action since storing has updated the page. Where possible I would extract links in advance though this would not satisfy the requirements of automated testing for example.

Comment: @QHarr the elements going stale won’t really matter much at this stage because this is supposed to be a script that will download content from the accessed pages. After the content is downloaded from the targeted pages their  elements aren’t really needed. Your comment however might be useful if I decide to add more functionality later on (check for new updates, access more info for data storage purposes etc..). Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "_following instance_"? Is it that you want to find the pdf button inside the current `elem`? If so see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/get-all-child-elements (You are currently searching in the entire document).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am trying to loop over all the elements in `issues_numb`, example shown in screenshot 1. But also to check if there's a PDF icon button for each instance of  `issues_numb` (for each `elem`) and instantiate an according course of action. At this point the code loops over every object in `elem` but at each time clicks the first pdf icon it finds as it is the first child element of the class `"//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']"`. I need it to click to do the following for each `elem` in `issues_number`: check if pdf icon available, if yes, click the according PDF icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find elements inside of elements using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400472/how-do-i-find-elements-inside-of-elements-using-selenium-with-python)

Comment: Try to use .// in stead of // in your loops. // means it will always search from root, not the context. The . Means start from the context.

Comment: You should be able to write something like `elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")` as described in the duplicate target above.

Comment: @double_wizz here is some docs I found: [Find Element From Element](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/web_element/#find-element-from-element)

Comment: Why is there a ***trailing space*** in four of the class names? - `class="pages "`, `class="article-list-item-content-block "`, `class="content-overflow "`, and `class="tools "`

Comment: Why is there a ***trailing space*** in one of the XPath expressions? - `"//section[@class='article-list-item-content-block ']"`". To match the trailing space in the HTML attribute?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, I have imitated the exact attributes that show in the HTML code. I have added trailing spaces when they were there in the source code.

Comment: Or in other words, what is the purpose of the ***trailing spaces***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve a situation like this, i.e., only having access to an identifier that is shared by multiple elements (in my case a class name that is shared by multiple PDF icons), is to specify a context in which to look.

This way, the driver will only look in the HTML code that is relevant to the specific area of search you're after. More on this [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/web_element/#find-element-from-element). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400472/how-do-i-find-elements-inside-of-elements-using-selenium-with-python) too, but Selenium's proper syntax has changed since then. This is syntax is the updated version:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tag['targeted_context']")
for elem in elements:
    targeted_element = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tag[@class='targeted_class']")
```

<sub>(Answer by @AbdulAzizBarkat in comments.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When you start an XPath expression with a double slash(`//`), the engine starts looking from the root everywhere in the content.

Therefore you should change the XPath expressions inside the loops by adding a `.` in front of the `//`. This way, you tell the engine to use the current context instead of the root.

Just to give you an idea, your code should look like this.

*Btw: it's good practice to share the actual HTML content, so your code and question is easier to understand.*

```
issues_numb = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='issue ember-view']")

for elem in issues_numb:

    button = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click(elem).perform()
    check_buttons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
    checking_size_buttons = len(str(check_buttons))
    if checking_size_buttons > 0:
        tools_box = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='buttons noselect']")

        for box in tools_box:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
            pdf_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
            parent_tab = driver.current_window_handle
            click_pdf = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pdf_icon).click(pdf_icon).perform()
            time.sleep(10)
            print(driver.current_url)
            check_need_to_sign_in()
            driver.switch_to.window(parent_tab)
```

Comment: Could you please check the updated version of the question? I have added the HTML code and hopefully made my question clearer.