# Is it possible to scrape dynamic ID of a web element using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there some sort of method/technique that allows the script to fetch the ID (of a specific web element using a selenium script? I am asking this as I am in a [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138565/locating-specific-instance-of-a-class-located-using-xpath-selenium) where the following could be useful: 1) fetch the unique ID of the targeted element 2) store the IDs of the various instances of a class 3) use the list to dynamically build XPATHS that can later be passed to a `for` loop. If this isn't possible, any alternative ways that lead to the same result?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a ‚dynamic id‘ of an element is?

Comment: @doberkofler what I meant was an `ember.js` enabled element, which is assigned a ID at each session. I have removed this bit from the question though as it doesn't matter, in this case, whether it's dynamic or not. I need to catch the current ID of an element that would serve as a locator.

Answer (score 0):

Just grabbing the id of an element that can be identified by a locator is quite trivial:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//...")
id = element. get_attribute("id");
```

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`. Which kinda takes me to the point of the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138565/locating-specific-instance-of-a-class-located-using-xpath-selenium?noredirect=1#comment123990989_70138565) problem. How can I access web elements and store them as such to be able to pass them on.

Comment: You must better explain what you are trying to do, what code you use and what error you get where in your code.