# Python requests : status_code and requests.ok not working as expected

Tags: python, python-requests

In Pycharm, when I try either of the methods (`.status_code` or `.ok`), they are highlighted in green and when I hover over it I get this message: "Cannot find reference 'ok' in '**init**.pyi"

I am trying to create a loop that will keep going until my request's status code yields 200 (or `.ok = True`). However, when I run the code bellow the following gets printed infinitely : `<module 'requests.status_codes' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/status_codes.py'>`. So my while loop's condition is never met, meaning my request isn't successful? Or is it not checking in the first place?

I am trying to download pdf documents with this script and before adding the while loop with the nested if statement, the script downloaded empty documents with no extensions. Which is why I added the loop to the code in the first place. I thought that the loop would solve the problem as it would wait for the `get` request to be successful and then write the files. Are these two problems connected?

Also, my while statement is embedded in a `try/except` statement. If you think that can make a difference please ask me to add the code.

**My code:**

```
 import requests as req
 response = req.get(url, verify=False)
 while i < 1:
            print(req.ok)
            if req.ok == True:
                with open(f"{title_article[13:]}", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                i = + 1
```

Comment: What is `req`? From the errors/warnings it seems like its the `requests` module and you're treating it like a response object?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated the code

Comment: Should be `response.ok` and not `req.ok`? You're treating the requests module like it's a response

Comment: yes, my bad. I am a newbie. Thanks :) The other part isn't solved yet though. The files downloaded are still empty ones. I will ask this in another question though unless you have an answer for that too?

Comment: Glad it helped. Probably better to open another question, without know what `title_article` is, where it comes from and the contents of the response it's hard to say

Comment: @IainShelvington title_article is just a variable to which the title of the pdf is passed as a string. I get it (using selenium) before clicking the PDF by locating a the web element that contains a link to it. You can see it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138565/locating-specific-instance-of-a-class-located-using-xpath-selenium) (code has changed since then but not for this variable), but I have reached my questions limit for now.