# Python requests downloads empty files without extensions instead of PDF documents

Tags: python, macos, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to grab the URLs for various PDF documents and feed them to the requests library so I can download the PDFs. The request is successful as `print(response.ok)` returns `True`. Instead I get a an empty file that has no extensions, labeled "Document" by OS X (see screenshot below). I am not sure whether this is a website issue, a Mac OS one or a Chrome one.

This question is being discussed in [this](https://%20chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) chatroom if you need to ask something there.

**My code:**

```
issues_numb = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//section[@class='article-list-item-content-block ']")
parent_tab = driver.current_window_handle

for elem in issues_numb:
    title_article = elem.get_attribute("aria-label")
    print(title_article[13:])
    try:
        check_buttons = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
        print("pdf object found for", str(elem))
        checking_size_buttons = len(str(check_buttons))
        if checking_size_buttons > 0:
            pdf_icon = elem.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='icon fal fa-file-pdf']")
            click_pdf = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pdf_icon).click(pdf_icon).perform()
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
            # print(driver.current_url)
            check_need_to_sign_in()

            driver.switch_to.window(parent_tab)

def check_need_to_sign_in():

    new_tab = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(str(new_tab[-1]))
    url = driver.current_url

    i = 0
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box']")))
        print("Sign-in necessary")
        sign_in()
        response = req.get(url, verify=False)
        url = driver.current_url
        

        while i < 1:
            print(response.ok)
            if response.ok == True:
                with open(f"{title_article[13:]}", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                i = + 1
    except TimeoutException:
        print("No need to sign-in")
        time.sleep(5) #waiting to finish redirecting
        url = driver.current_url
        response = req.get(url, verify=False)
        while i < 1:
            print(response.ok)
            if response.ok == True:
                with open(f"{title_article[13:]}", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                i = + 1
```

[image]

**Added temporarily for @Jortega to see:**

*Download page before clicking:*

[image: download page before clicking]

*Download page after manually clicking:*

[image: download page after manually clicking]

Comment: Where you have written `with open(f"{title_article[13:]}", 'wb') as f:`, what do you think this will cause the file name to be? What does `title_article` look like before this line? You say you are expecting PDF documents, which implies that you expected a file name that ends with a `.pdf` extension. Does `title_article[13:]` actually contain `.pdf`? Did you *expect* it to? Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. I have given you some pointed questions above to help you diagnose and isolate the problem. You are supposed to take those steps proactively. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Having done that work, you should find that the problem isn't *caused by* anything to do with Selenium or `requests`; the problem is that `title_article` doesn't have the right value. You haven't shown the code that sets that value, so we can't help you with it.

Comment: No it doesn't. When I tried to add the ".pdf" extension to the f string it produced a pdf document but adobe acrobat gave this message: Adobe Acrobat could not open 'name of the relevant article' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded). title_article is just a variable to which the title of the pdf is passed as a string. I You can see it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138565/locating-specific-instance-of-a-class-located-using-xpath-selenium).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Kindly note that I have spent a good while trying to figure this out. Tried a bunch of things too. It's probably because I am a self taught beginner that things aren't that obvious to me. For example it doesn't make sense to me why passing the name of the title as a formatted string could be a problem. Could you elaborate on why you think it might be the problem? I have added the relevant code for the variable.

Comment: What happens when you manually click link to the PDF?  It sounds like this could take some trouble shooting. Just @ me in this chatroom.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium

Comment: @Jortega I get asked where I want to download the document and how I want to name it. Could skipping this step be the reason? If so, any solutions in mind.